# javax.xml.ws.Service to consume SOAP service via SSL

Tags: java, soap, ssl, jax-ws

I want to consume a SOAP service via HTTPS. I have written a client to do that. I didn't use automatic class generation because the target service runs on multiple systems so the service URL changes during runtime.

This is the implementation using JAX-WS:

```
public class SAPClient implements Callable<...> {

private Service service = null;
private SOAPMessage response = null;
private boolean submitted = false;
private boolean successfull = false;
private QName serviceName;
private QName portName;
private SAPResult result = new SAPResult();
private Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = null;
private SOAPBody resBody = null;
private SapConnector connector;

public SAPClient(EricAgent agent, SapConnector connector) {
    this.connector = connector;
    serviceName = new QName(connector.getUrl(), Environment.SAP_CLIENT_SERVICE_NAME);
    portName = new QName(connector.getUrl(), Environment.SAP_CLIENT_PORT);
    this.service = Service.create(serviceName);
    service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, connector.getUrl());
    this.successfull = false;
}

(...)

public synchronized void invoke() throws SOAPException {
    try {
        dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);

        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
        SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
        SOAPPart part = message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope env = part.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = env.getBody();

        SOAPElement operation = body.addChildElement(
                Environment.SAP_CLIENT_OPERATION_NAME,
                Environment.SAP_CLIENT_TARGET_NAMESPACE.getPrefix(),
                Environment.SAP_CLIENT_TARGET_NAMESPACE.getURI());

        // Add ticket
        SOAPElement ticketValue = operation.addChildElement("ITicket");
        ticketValue.addTextNode(...);

        // Add "Informationsprotokoll"
        String resultString = buildEricResultString(agent);
        SOAPElement xmlValue = operation.addChildElement("IXml");
        xmlValue.addTextNode(resultString);
        message.saveChanges();

        Response<SOAPMessage> sapResponse = dispatch.invokeAsync(message);

        long waitingTime = 0;

        while (true) {
            if (waitingTime > Environment.SAP_CLIENT_TIME_OUT) {
                //... handle timeout
            }

            if (sapResponse.getContext() != null) {
                Environment.LOGGER.debug("got response");
                response = sapResponse.get();
                submitted = true;
                successfull = result.returnCode.equals("0");

                //...

                break;
            }

            wait(1000);
            waitingTime += 1000;
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Environment.LOGGER.error(null, ex);
        this.submitted = false;
        this.successfull = false;
    }
}

}
```

I want to consume this service via SSL now. Can you explain me how I tell the `Service` class to use a specific certificate? How do I pass the keystore for example... I googled around and didn't find satisfying results. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**

By adding:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", certPath);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", certPass);
```

I could get SSL to work - thanks zuxqoj!

The output looked liked this and the connection timed out:

```
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: ***
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=***, OU=I0020498236, OU=SAP Web AS, O=SAP Trust Community, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=***, OU=I0020498236, OU=SAP Web AS, O=SAP Trust Community, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x20120718050810
  Valid from Wed Jul 18 07:08:10 CEST 2012 until Fri Jan 01 01:00:01 CET 2038

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

To get pass the timeout I had to pass this property to the JVM and the http(s) request went through:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your code before SOAP call

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",certificatePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", certificatePassword));
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
```

you can download .cer certificate from server url and convert it into jks using command

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

now you need certificate corresponding to each target server and in your system somewhere you need to maintain mapping between server url and certificate